# Is there any way to get the name of a function from a user and execute?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a custom class. In the class, i want to create a function that takes a parameter(like a function name) of a public function to execute in the class function if conditions are met.

ex:
myclass.Firefunc "NameOfPublicFunctiontoExecute"

Is this possible?
thanks

Comment: You need to first create an *instance* of your class, using the `New` keyword.

Comment: Within your class instance you can probably use something like `CallByName(Me, "nameOfFunction", vbMethod)`

Comment: @TimWilliams, the callbyname() is what i am looking for. thanks wish i can give you credit.